# Azure Powershell - Read all rows from Azure Table with SAS token (read-only)

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-table-storage, azure-powershell

If I have a read only SAS token for a particular Azure Storage table, how can I use `Get-AzureStorageTableRowAll` with it? Whatever I tried doesn't work!

Comment: Please share what all things have you tried so far and the issues you're running into.

Comment: Could you provide your script and error message in your question?

Comment: Sorry, been busy today but I'll do it tomorrow

Comment: ok, I tried to create the script with Az module (as I don't use AzureRm anymore) but there are no `Get-AzureStorageTableRowAll` command! so now I don't even think it can be done...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Az module it's not possible at the moment because `Get-AzureStorageTableRowAll` does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

When generate the sas token, you should also include the `list` permission:

[image]

Please try the code below:

```
$saContext = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName "account_name" -SasToken "your sas token"
$table = Get-AzureStorageTable -Name $tableName -Context $saContext
Get-AzureStorageTableRowAll -table $table
```

And test result:

[image]

Comment: Maybe my question wasn't clear enough - I'm using sas token *for the table*, not for the account.

Comment: I will do but in ~12 hours

Comment: Sorry, been very busy. Later today, I promise.